# How to configure custom solr instance to use Morfologik?

Tags: solr, polish

I have a custom solr instance running in tomcat. I followed tomcat deployment tutorial in SolrWiki. I want to index my data which are in Polish language and I want to use Morfologik. So i followed http://solr.pl/en/2012/04/02/solr-4-0-and-polish-language-analysis/. I've created lib folder in SOLR_HOME, added all libraries to this folder, changed schema to use solr.MorfologikFilterFactory but i still get such error:

'collection1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:   Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType „text_pl”: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error loading class "solr.MorfologikFilterFactory"'

I assume there is a problem with paths. I hope so, because if not it might by quite hard to solve...

Anybody can help me? Thanks!

Comment: What Solr version are you using ?

Comment: Lets maybe use in solrconfig add all libraries with absolute localization

Comment: Same error for my custom plugin. no solutions till now.

Answer (score 0):

you can add lib path to the solrconfig.xml - see the xml supplied with example.
are you using the SolrCloud mode or standalone?